# classpaths with Java Web Services,classNotFoundException

Tags: java, web-services, classpath

Serious problems here, I don't know what to do, been at this hours. Getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: User
```

Here's my code:

```
public class BookingServerPublisher{

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Starting web Service,Press Ctrl + C to stop\n");
    // 1st argument is the publication URL
    // 2nd argument is an SIB instance
    Endpoint.publish("http://127.0.0.1:9876/bs", new BookingServerImpl());
}
}

@WebService(endpointInterface = "bs.BookingServer")

public class BookingServerImpl implements BookingServer{

User users = new User();

public void initData(){
    users.loadUsers();
}
}

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)

public interface BookingServer{

@WebMethod void initData();

}

class BookingClient{

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9876/bs?wsdl");
    // Qualified name of the service:
    // 1st arg is the service URI
    // 2nd is the service name published in the WSDL
    QName qname = new QName("http://bs/", "BookingServerImplService");
    // Create, in effect, a factory for the service.
    Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
    // Extract the endpoint interface, the service "port".
    BookingServer eif = service.getPort(BookingServer.class);

    eif.initData();
}
}

package bs;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class User{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

static ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();    //Dynamic List of all the User objects

String name;
String password;
String level;
boolean isAdmin = false;

User(){
    super();
}

//Method for loading User objects from data file
static void loadUsers(){
    try {
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("UsersData");
        ObjectInputStream read = new ObjectInputStream(stream);

        while(stream.available() != 0){
            Object obj = read.readObject();
             if(obj instanceof User){
                User users = (User) obj;
                userList.add(users);
            }
        }
        stream.close();
        read.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Method for saving User objects to data file
static void saveUsers(){

    try {
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("UsersData");
        ObjectOutputStream write = new ObjectOutputStream(stream);

        for(int i = 0; i < userList.size();i++){
            if(userList.get(i) instanceof User){
                write.writeObject(userList.get(i));
            }
        }
        stream.close();
        write.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The package in all files is `bs` and I'm executing it as `java bs.BookingServerPublisher`,

`java bs.BookingClient` from the folder containing the `bs` folder,i.e. `bs`' parent directory, the `BookingServerPublisher` console throws the error.

Anyone can help me with this I really appreciate it.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` is exactly what it sounds. Either the Java-file is not compiled into a class file, or you got the path wrong (or some other problem). Use your IDE to figure out what's wrong with the class for which you receive the error. If it's in different folder, could it be permissions/owner problem ?

Comment: Thanks for you answer.. the file is definately compiled into a class file and sits in the same directory as the other files in the package

Comment: did you try running `java -cp . bs.BookingServerPublisher`?

Comment: Which line is the exception coming from?  If I'm remembering right, [`ClassNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) implies a dynamic link is failing, not a static link.  In other words, it is reserved for when you try to load a class via Reflection, not when your class statically references another class that's not available.  In the latter case, you'd get a [`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html).  So I assume it's this line? `Object obj = read.readObject();`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it's the deserialization that's failing:

```
Object obj = read.readObject();
```

It's failing because the object's fully-qualified class name when it was serialized was `User` (hence the exception message "`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: User`").  But your code base only has a class named `bc.User` (since it's in the "bc" package).  From Java's perspective, these are entirely different and unrelated classes.

You need the same class to be used on both ends of the serialization.